# Saving an Excel sheet in a current directory with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a sheet in vba Excel. I would like to save it the current directory, but not in absolute path, then, when this is executed somewhere else, there won't be problem.

Can somebody help ?

Answer (score 21):

I am not clear exactly what your situation requires but the following may get you started. The key here is using `ThisWorkbook.Path` to get a relative file path:

```
Sub SaveToRelativePath()
    Dim relativePath As String
    relativePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & ActiveWorkbook.Name
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=relativePath
End Sub
```

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.FullName` provides the filepath and name.

Answer (score 8):

VBA has a CurDir keyword that will return the "current directory" as stored in Excel.  I'm not sure all the things that affect the current directory, but definitely opening or saving a workbook will change it.

```
MyWorkbook.SaveAs CurDir & Application.PathSeparator & "MySavedWorkbook.xls"
```

This assumes that the sheet you want to save has never been saved and you want to define the file name in code.

Comment: `CurDir` pointed to `%UserProfile%\Documents` for me, which is different from the location of the spreadsheet. What you want is probably `ActiveWorkbook.Path`, which is the current directory of the active spreadsheet.

Comment: If the workbook has already been saved, then just use the `.Save` method and you don't need to know the path. If it hasn't been saved, then the `.Path` property will be a null string so it won't help.

Answer (score 5):

If the Path is omitted the file will be saved automaticaly in the current directory.
Try something like this:

***`ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "Filename.xslx"`***

Answer (score 2):

Taking this one step further, to save a file to a relative directory, you can use the replace function. Say you have your workbook saved in: c:\property\california\sacramento\workbook.xlsx, use this to move the property to berkley:

```
workBookPath = Replace(ActiveWorkBook.path, "sacramento", "berkley")
myWorkbook.SaveAs(workBookPath & "\" & "newFileName.xlsx"
```

Only works if your file structure contains one instance of the text used to replace. YMMV.